# wordpress не хочет отображать картинки в теле новости

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Дорогие друзья, у меня есть небольшая проблема, которую я никак не могу решить. Начнем сначала:
Самописный сайт нужно было перенести на вордпресс двиг, все бы ничего, но дьявол кроется в деталях - картинки были заданы очень странным образом (отдельная база данных со своей таблицей и ключами) + картинок более 7т шт. + картинки в тексте были заданы не обычным способом, а именно <#pic#1157#0#0#0##>. Изменил таблицу БД, залил ее в БД вордпреса с названием images, написал для этого дела скрипт https://pastebin.com/xsjheBnE Вполне сносно работает и вытягивает картинки из бд, в итоге получается , то есть, выводить картинки в теле новости он должен априори, путь правильный, картинка есть, если вбить ссылку просто в браузер, то он ее открывает! Но сам вордпресс отказывается показывать данную картинку в теле новости и на сайте в целом, пробовал менять тему оформления - эффект тот-же. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А то что у тэга img scr вместо src   - это нормально?

Comment: боже... ломал голову четыре дня...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Это ж надо было так тупануть...]

Благодарю за содействие, иногда взгляд со стороны куда лучше, чем свой собственный. Смотрел в упор и не видел такую глупую ошибку.